# React app gets blank page when emulates with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, deployment

I have Firebase project with multiple folders in `public` folder. One of the folders with React app initialized in it. So, my project tree looks something like this.

```
firebase-project
\---public
    |---folder1
    |---folder2
    \---react-app
        |---build
        |---public
```

I don't have `build` folder in root folder. `public` folder is generated by Firebase.

Here's my `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run `firebase serve` or `firebase emulators:start`, `index.html` in `folder1` and `folder2` displays correctly, but not `react-app`. `localhost:5000/react-app/build` and`localhost:5000/react-app/public` shows blank page.

But if you provide the path to `react-app` app in `public` key, it works.

```json
"public": "public/react-app/build",
```

But in this case, I can't navigate to `folder1` and `folder2` paths

I tried using `"rewrites"` to redirect to the `build` path but that didn't work either. And it works fine when providing direct path to `react-app` in `public` key.

What am I missing?

Comment: May be you might have misplaced your google.json file

Comment: @Anee is it android related? The project is on the web

Comment: yes  , its related to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with where Webpack searches for assets. And there's nothing wrong with this.

You see, when Webpack creates build (using `npm run build` in React), in `index.html` file it points to assets like this `/static/js/%name%.chunk.js`. Because in `firebase.json` my `public` key points to `public` folder, it searches for `static` folder in the root. But with this structure, assets sit in `/react-app/build/static/`.

Once you point to the right place, everything's working.

I will definitely need to rearrange my structure because a lot of unnecessary files deploys to firebase.